# Probability - mutual independence lacking pairwise independence?

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose P(A∩B∩C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) and A,B are independent, B,C are independent but nothing was given about A and C.

Can you still assume A,B,C are independent?

I looked up mutual independence, and it told me that A and C being independent must also hold in order to claim that all three events are independent. So I was trying to come up with a simple coin toss or rolling a die type of counterexample, but couldn't form one up. Can someone help formulate one, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Clearly no , since you might have $A=C$ with $B$ independent of them

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In what sense does $A=C$ not work? Providing $P(A)=P(C)$ is not $0$ or $1$ then $A$ and $C$ are not independent of each other but are independent of $B$ so this would be a counter-example

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am reading "A,B are independent, B,C are independent" as "$A$ is independent of $B$ and $B$ is independent of $C$" not as "$A\cap B$ is independent of $B \cap C$".  Otherwise why say *independent* twice

Comment: You contradict me and contradict yourself! @Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg).$ This can model a fair coin toss. Consider now
$$
A=\{X=0\}, \quad B=\emptyset \quad\text{and} \quad C= \{X=1\}.
$$
Note that $A,B$ and $B,C$  are independent as well as
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2}  = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(C).
$$
Yet
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap C) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0 \neq \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(C)
$$
and thus $A,C$ are not independent. Hence $A,B,C$ are not independent.

Comment: Thank you. Having B as a not-possible event never came up to me. Definitely enlightening.